# Программно определить вид девайса

Tags: android-sdk, android

Можно ли программно определить девайс, на котором запущен софт: планшет или смартфон? Определять по разрешению экрана - не вариант, на многих смартфонах оно не хуже, чем на планшетах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда то изучал этот вопрос. В целом, пришел к выводу, что все, что меньше 7 дюймов, можно считать смартфоном, а то, что больше - планшетом.  На следующей итерации сделал иначе - все что маленькое (5 дюймов и меньше) - включалось в режиме смарта, более 7 - в режиме планшета. Для всех, больше 5 в настройках давал возможность выбрать интерфейс.

После долгих гуглений на просторах и консультаций с андроид адвокатами (это специалисты по решению вопросов по андроиду), был получен такой код

```
private bool isTabletModeDetermined = false;
private bool isTabletMode = false;
//....
public static boolean isTablet(Context paramContext) {
    if (!isTabletModeDetermined) {
      if (paramContext.getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp>= 600)
        isTabletMode = true;
      isTabletModeDetermined = true;
    }
    return isTabletMode;
  }
```

Говорят, что в gTalk используется что то подобное.

Comment: Видимо, предполагается, что 

- разрешение экрана в андроиде на ходу не меняется;
- что системный вызов очень дорого "стоит", раз его нужно кэшировать.

Comment: Кеширование на андроиде (и не только) очень сильно помогает в плане произоводительности.

А вот разрешение на ходу если  меняется, то подозреваю, что с большой вероятностью, приложение будет перезапущено. (имеется опыт с sdcard - когда ее вытягивают, а приложение использует ее, то андроид просто перезапускает приложение. И никаких проблем:))

@gecube, Вам известны устройства, где можно налету изменять разрешения?

Comment: @KoVadim, не уверен. Но вроде есть утилиты для смены density налету.

Comment: Во всяких кастомных прошивках. циагене, к примеру. Но я думаю, оно перезапустит приложение.

Comment: Это не претензия, ведь сколько лет прошло, но забавно звучит, что 7 дюймов скорей всего планшет, galaxy s20 ultra вышел из чата

Comment: galaxy s20 ultra - 6.9, так что даже через 8 лет, мой ответ ещё актуальный. Самсунг также в курсе моего ответа.